# Pack/unpack short into int

Tags: c++, c, cuda, bit-manipulation, c++-amp

I want to pack/unpack two signed 16 bit integers into a 32 bit integer. However, I'm not getting it to quite work.

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

```
template <typename T>
int read_s16(T& arr, int idx) restrict(amp)
{
    return static_cast<int>((arr[idx/2] >> ((idx % 2) * 16)) << 16) >> 16;
}

template<typename T>
void write_s16(T& arr, int idx, int val) restrict(amp)
{
    // NOTE: arr is zero initialized
    concurrency::atomic_fetch_or(&arr[idx/2], (static_cast<unsigned int>(val) & 0xFFFF) << ((idx % 2) * 16));
}
```

The function return/arguments must be as I have defined. The `lo` and `hi` are written from different threads (thus the atomic_or), and the read must return a single 32 bit value.

16 bit integer arithmetics are not supported on the target platform.

Example:

```
array<int> ar(1); // Container

write_s16(ar, 0, -16);
write_s16(ar, 1, 5);

assert(read_s16(ar, 0) == -16);
assert(read_s16(ar, 1) == 5);
```

Comment: Could you give some example of input and output?

Comment: Something inside me objects to the notion of concurrently packing data into a single `int`...

Comment: Kerrek SB: The code is run on the GPU.

Comment: Are you just wanting to store them and pass them along to someone else?  How do you deal with the signs?  Can you just put it into a uint16_t[2]?  It seems from your question that you are just packaging them up, so I'd recommend working with unsigned data.

Comment: The data is signed, which is what makes this a bit complicated, and it has to be put into a unsigned int or int array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These atomic operations in C++ AMP also have the following limitations:

- You should not mix atomic and normal (non-atomic) reads and writes.
  Normal reads may not see the results of atomic writes to the same
  memory location. Normal writes should not be mixed with atomic writes
  to the same memory location. If your program does not comply with
  these criteria then this will lead to an undefined result.
- Atomic
  operations do not imply a memory fence of any sort. Atomic operations
  may be reor-dered. This differs from the behavior of interlocked
  operations in C++.

It would seem like you are violating the first of these.

Comment: Ade is correct, of course. For any other issues with atomics, please consult the blog post which has this and other information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/01/04/c-amp-s-atomic-operations.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It seems overly complicated, and there are strange operations in there.

Usually, you'd just do it like this:

```
int32_t Pack(int16_t a, int16_t b)
{
   return (int32_t)((((uint32_t)a)<<16)+(uint32_t)b);
}

int16_t UnpackA(int32_t x)
{
   return (int16_t)(((uint32_t)x)>>16);
}

int16_t UnpackB(int32_t x)
{
   return (int16_t)(((uint32_t)x)&0xffff);
}
```

Note that I used the types with explicit bit sizes to illustrate what's going on. I also took the liberty to assume that you want an "integer", not an "unsigned integer".

Answer (score 2):

The code below works fine for me in MSVC. As you can see it's the same as your code in principle.

Could the problem be that you forget to initialize the content of the array to zero? How does your platform handle negative numbers and casting to unsigned int?

```
template <typename T>
int read_s16(T& arr, int idx)
{
    return static_cast<int>((arr[idx/2] >> ((idx % 2) * 16)) << 16) >> 16;
}

template<typename T>
void write_s16(T& arr, int idx, int val)
{
    // NOTE: arr is zero initialized
    arr[idx/2] |= (static_cast<unsigned int>(val) & 0xFFFF) << ((idx % 2) * 16);
}

int main()
{
    int ar[2] = { 0,0 }; // container

    write_s16<int [2]>(ar, 0, -16);
    write_s16<int [2]>(ar, 1, 5);

    assert(read_s16<int [2]>(ar, 0) == -16);
    assert(read_s16<int [2]>(ar, 1) == 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hm, it works for me as well when running on the cpu, broken on gpu. Might be that GPU handles right shifting sign differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for packing:

```
int_32 = (int16_1 & 0x0000FFFF) | (int16_2 & 0xFFFF0000);
```

For unpacking:

```
int16_MSB = (int_32 >> 16) & 0xFFFF;
int16_LSB = int_32 & 0xFFFF;
```